# Pine Script - How to change variable value of previous bars?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to calculate the number of bars difference to specific bar of a specific time.
Some bars obviously are older than the specific time, which is a user input.

I want to change the value of a variable (outvalue) of historical bars but that does not seem to be possible in PineScript?

Thanks in advance , something like below conceptually.

```
//@version=4

study("Test")
StartDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.time, defval=timestamp("24 May 2021 00:00 +0800"))

int StartBar =0
var OutValue = 0

if (dayofmonth(StartDate) == dayofmonth(time) and month(StartDate) == month(time) and year(StartDate) == year(time))
    StartBar := bar_index

for i = 0 to StartBar
OutValue[i] = abs(i-StartBar)

plot(OutValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StartDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.time, defval=timestamp("24 May 2021 00:00 +0800"))

int StartBar = 0
var int OutValue = 0

bool ts_bar = false

if time >= StartDate and time[1] < StartDate
    ts_bar := true

OutValue := barssince(ts_bar)

plot(OutValue)
```

This will tell you how many bars since the starting time. Also you can't assign historical values of variables like you have with `OutValue[i] =`

Comment: thanks Rumpy, so a further conceptual/structural question, is there  a way for pine script to use some entire history specifics on individual bar? e.g. just making up an example, I would like to say use the volatility of the most recent 30 days, and compare that to last 10 years historically. is there a way?